# Whatsapp Web as a Google Chrome webapp cannot take hangul input with ibus-setup

Tags: keyboard, google-chrome, keyboard-layout, ibus, korean

I am running xubuntu and use i3wm. Then I want to have Korean keyboard layout. I have followed suggestions on [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/456133/126560). Basically what I did was install `ibus-setup-hangul` and then run `ibus-setup`. Under "Input Method" I add Korean. Then I logout and login.

Everything works fine, and I can switch between Korean and English seamlessly using keyboard shortcuts. I even get it working in Discord.

I also have Whatsapp Web in Google Chrome that I turned into a webapp (from options: More Tools > Create Shortcuts > tick Open as window). However whenever I tried to type in Korean there, the input box glitched. I typed one full syllable, and it is gone as it switches to the next syllable. I think it might only be the display, so I tried to type a full word, but I only got a truncated, and somehow duplicated text when I press enter to send.

Everywhere else on Google Chrome though, I can get it working just fine.

I am not sure what went wrong and whose fault is it. Is it a bug on Google Chrome, ibus, or just whatsapp web?

Comment: Does it make a difference if you open a terminal and run `ibus restart`?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson no unfortunately it does not make any difference

Comment: Ok. Maybe you should try some Google Chrome or WhatsApp forum then.